# generar numero de factura consecutivo en laravel? multiusuario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Actualmente tengo un sistema de ventas(anteriormente generaba el numero manual) pero necesito que lo genere automático y debido a que lo van a operar varios usuarios a la vez, deseo un procedimiento que no duplique números

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme
trabajo con laravel y mysql

El numero de factura comenzaría en 01, el procedimiento lo podria realizar en mysql o en laravel, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, deseo un procedimiento que me permita generar numeros correlativos, es decir; no se pierda con la factura eliminada, cualquier orientacion que me puedan dar para buscar información de cómo hacerlo es bienbenida, saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta puede acabar cerrada sea por qué es demasiado amplia y/o parece basada en opiniones, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: no enteniendo por que? no puedo poner código porque es la pregunta que estoy haciendo precisamente

Comment: Por que solo expones lo que deseas obtener pero no tenemos evidencia alguna de lo que has hecho y que fallos te ha dado, como ya sabes las preguntas así no son bien recibidas, investiga, trata y cuando algo falle eres más que bienvenido a preguntar

Comment: El problema es que tu pregunta es como muy amplia... queres la respuesta en laravel o en mysql? necesitas el numero antes al abrir la factura o alcanza al cerrarla? quien decide el orden numerico? que pasa si una factura se cancela? o sea.. hay montones de variables que son necesarias para pensar una respuesta para esto...

Comment: Edite la pregunta para explicar mejor lo que deseo realizar, gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: ok. usa un trigger y asigna el numero al terminar... si hay una factura eliminada en el medio, no tenes solucion... tuviste algun problema en particular probando cualquier cosa?

Comment: Gracias finalmente lo resolví desde laravel, saludos

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, @IngDePáez, pero, no es el auto increment un numero correlativo ?

Comment: si pero según la documentación no se recomienda utilizarlos gracias por consultar